# Sum types in Racket/TypedRacket

Tags: racket, typed-racket

What would be the Racket/TypedRacket equivalent of Haskell's sum types?

For example:
`data MusicGenre = HeavyMetal | Pop | HardRock`

Comment: Idk much about racket, but it sounds like you're describing a discriminated union type. The official Racket docs on this are here: https://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-guide/types.html#%28part._.Union_.Types%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`define-type`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/special-forms.html#%28form._%28%28lib._typed%2Fracket%2Fbase..rkt%29._define-type%29%29) and a [union](https://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/type-ref.html#%28form._%28%28lib._typed-racket%2Fbase-env%2Fbase-types..rkt%29._.U%29%29) of symbols for this kind of sum type:

```lisp
$ racket -I typed/racket
Welcome to Racket v8.7 [cs].
> (define-type MusicGenre (U 'HeavyMetal 'Pop 'HardRock))
> (define x (ann 'Pop MusicGenre))
> (define y (ann 'Jazz MusicGenre))
string:1:15: Type Checker: type mismatch
  expected: MusicGenre
  given: 'Jazz
  in: (quote Jazz)
 [,bt for context]
> (define (best-genre [g : MusicGenre]) (if (eq? g 'HardRock) "You know it" "Loser"))
> best-genre
- : (-> MusicGenre String)
#<procedure:best-genre>
> (best-genre 'Jazz)
string:1:12: Type Checker: type mismatch
  expected: MusicGenre
  given: 'Jazz
  in: (quote Jazz)
 [,bt for context]
> (best-genre 'HardRock)
- : String
"You know it"
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also be interested in `define-datatype` provided by [typed-racket-datatype](https://docs.racket-lang.org/typed-racket-datatype/index.html). You can combine that with `match` from [racket/match](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html) to branch on the cases.